# Public "Snapshots" for history mode nodes

Tags: node

Is there a public service that provides copies of the whole blockchain? I dont mean full snapshots but the real context/store for archive nodes. I need this in order to run a local tzscan api. I only found https://tezosshots.com/ but this did not work with my node as it said this is not a correct mdb file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.chainlayer.io/ used to propose such archive contexts as well.

Comment: yeah they only said "soon", so nothing i can find

Comment: It seems that it is possible to download an archive context on https://www.chainlayer.io/. Only the help is tagged as "soon".

Comment: Thanks i just saw it! I will try it out and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not a good idea to retrieve someone's else whole storage (context and store). Indeed, the data may have been altered in different ways and it could be harmful.

If you want to get the chain in archive mode, it is recommended to bootstrap it from scratch (don't forget the `--history-mode archive` option when running the node). It is indeed a quite long process but it is currently the safest way.

An alternative solution would be a `tezos-node` command which aims to *reconstruct* an archive storage from a full one. When called, it will re-apply all the operations of the chain in order to reconstruct the whole ledger state (context). It is safe as it relies on the standard block validation. Such a feature should be available soon …

Comment: thanks for your answer! unfortunately syncing from scratch is not an option is it would took a few weeks. Is there no other provider that provides a full archive to download?

Comment: @DZDomi Unfortunately, this is the only way. Import a 'full' snapshot to your node then run a reconstruct to convert it to archive. It takes about 7 days to complete. You can run a second node, locally, that only connects to your primary node to fetch the data, which will go much faster than trying to sync directly from the network.